# Php newline not using \n\r

Tags: php

I generated a list of data from database.

```
$string='';
$array  = $ocidb ->ORASelectRecord();
foreach ($array as $list){
$string .= $list[0]['Column'].",";
}
```

The $string will now have

ResultA,ResultB,ResultC,ResultD ....etc

I want ask how to make the string to have newline after the comma?

Meaning instead of having

```
$string = "ResultA,ResultB,ResultC,ResultD";
```

I want to change it to become

```
$string = "ResultA,
ResultB,
ResultC,
ResultD";
```

adding \n\r after the comma doesn't work.

Comment: You mean `\r\n` right ? ;) if that's a web page (XAMPP for example) use `<br>`

Comment: either way \r\n or \n\r didn't work

Comment: @user1761160 and what is the purpose behind this string?

Comment: Try [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: \r\n will add a line break to the source generated by the php script. If you'd like to add a line break to the content displayed on screen in the browser, use <br> - Have a look at the page-source in the browser, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: hi Jogesh, actually the data generated are emails. over 100 email to be send using php email(). But when send as long string no mail send. it works only if there is a new line in the string

Comment: enhzflep adding \r\n actually add in more character to the string instead of breaking the line with enter

Comment: Fred, using nl2br is to add <br> as default. it does not work for me either

Answer (score 3):

Just add it after the comma:

```
$string .= $list[0]['Column'].",\n";
```

Or the fancier way:

```
$string = join(",\n", array_map(function($list) {
    return $list[0]['Column'];
}, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code output is being displayed in an HTML environment you can use the `<br>` tag to insert a line break.

Comment: Martin, is not just simply use <br>

Answer (score 0):

Just add only `\n` and everything works fine

Comment: you tried this? `$string .= $list[0]['Column'].",\n";` works well for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$text = <<<'EOT'
   ResultA,
   ResultB,
   ResultC,
   ResultD
EOT;
```

or: `\r\n`

or (web):
`<br>`

Answer (score 0):

You simple need to add `\n` after Comma (`,`)

```
foreach ($array as $list){
    $string .= $list[0]['Column'].",\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
But, if you test on browser it will look as single line. View the html source (Ctrl+U in Mozilla Firefox) to look the plain text result.

```
$string='';
$array  = $ocidb ->ORASelectRecord();
foreach ($array as $list){
   $string .= $list[0]['Column'].",\n";
}
```

If you want the seperate lines shown properly in browser as HTML, then you can use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or use <br/> instead of \n

```
   $string .= $list[0]['Column'].",<br/>";
```